# Can I place an object in air - 360 angle (random position) without click instead of find plane in unity Vuforia mid air

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to show my 3D object in mid air.  Currently my object shows on click event, but I don't want click event. I just want the object shown in a random position in midair.

Comment: you can set a timer in update and instantiate your object in random position. you can  generate x = Random.Range(a,b), y = Random.Range(a,b), z = Random.Range(a,b) and create a posiiton = Vector3(x,y,z)

Comment: i am asking about vuforia,currently i have added midairpositionbehaviour.confirmanchorposition but i dont want click event + i want to track mid air and fetch object in randome position at 360 angle.

Answer (score 1):

if I break your question into two, then,

1. Vuforia uses "Anchor input Listener Behavior" to receive the input for the mid-air anchor. I am not sure it will work without a click event.

[image] 
you have to click to lock the mid-air target, you can gamify it by showing a pop up "click to start". 
However, there is always a way out. If you go through PlaneManager.cs class then you fill find a method "PlaceObjectInMidAir", you can carefully build logic and call the following lines in Update method but for one time.

```
if (TrackingStatusIsTrackedAndNormal)
{
    this.contentPositioningBehaviour.AnchorStage = this.midAirAnchor;
    this.contentPositioningBehaviour.PositionContentAtMidAirAnchor(midAirTransform);
    UtilityHelper.EnableRendererColliderCanvas(this.midAirAugmentation, true);

    this.midAirAugmentation.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    UtilityHelper.RotateTowardCamera(this.midAirAugmentation);
}
```

2. To spawn the gameobjects randomly in 360 degree, you can use instantiate method in random position with "Random.insideUnitSphere" [see the link]
   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-insideUnitSphere.html
   then make that object child of mid-air Achor "Anchor_MidAir".

Hope my answer would give you a start push.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> currently my object show on click event i don't wont click event just object show on random position of midair

If I understand that correctly, your object is shown when the mouse is clicked, and instead of this you want to show it in a random position. Here's what you should do:

- Don't listen to that click event. If you don't want something to happen on click, just don't write any code that does that!
- To teleport an object to a random position, decide what the minimum and maximum values for your object's position are, and do the following:

  ```
  yourGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(
      Random.Range(minX, maxX),
      Random.Range(minY, maxY),
      Random.Range(minZ, maxZ));
  ```

Comment: i am asking about vuforia,currently i have added midairpositionbehaviour.confirmanchorposition but i dont want click event + i want to track mid air and fetch object in randome position at 360 angle.